# How can I use the functions of "stack.c" inside the file "graph.c"?

Tags: c, data-structures, graph, stack

I'm trying to use the algorithm called "Topoligical Sorting" for graphs.

For use it, I've created two data structures: graph and stack. Both of them are written separately.

I'm trying to use the stack data structure (and your operations like push and pop) inside the file graph.c. For this, I've written:

```
#include "stack.h"
```

inside of the graph.c and, when I'll compile it, There's no error.

Well, There's no compilation error when I create a stack s1 inside graph.c (see the code below):

```
Stack *s1 = init(); //Creates a stack s1
```

The problem arises when I try to use another operation of the stack (like push and pop). For example, if I write:

```
push(3,s1);
```

And try to compile it, the following error arises:

```
graph.c: In function `DIGRAPHdfs':
graph.c:71: parse error before `int'
graph.c:73: `v' undeclared (first use in this function)
graph.c:73: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
graph.c:73: for each function it appears in.)
```

The same error arises when I try to use the pop function.

Why I get this error compilation?

### Source files

#### graph.c

(Please, see the function `Digraphdfs` in this code, The error arises there)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "graph.h"
#include "stack.h"
#define maxV 10000


static int count, pre[maxV],lbl[maxV];

struct digraph {
 int V; 
 int A;
 int **adj;
};

//Cria a matriz de adjacÃªncias (utilizando a tÃ©cnica de vetor de ponteiros)
int **MATRIXint( int r, int c, int val) {
  Vertex i,j;
  int **m = malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
       m[i] = malloc(c*sizeof(int));
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
       for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
           m[i][j] = val;
  return m;
}


//Cria o digrafo com V vertices e V arcos
Digraph DIGRAPHinit(int V){
   Digraph G = malloc(sizeof *G);
   G->V = V;
   G->A = 0;
   G->adj = MATRIXint(V,V,0);
   return G;
}

//Insere o arco entre v e w
void DIGRAPHinsertA( Digraph G, Vertex v, Vertex w) {
  if (G->adj[v][w] == 0)
      {
    G->adj[v][w] = 1;
    G->A++;
    }
}

//Remove o arco entre v e w
void DIGRAPHremoveA( Digraph G, Vertex v, Vertex w){
  if (G->adj[v][w] == 1){
    G->adj[v][w] = 0;
    G->A--;
  }
}

void DIGRAPHshow(Digraph G){
   Vertex v,w;
   for (v = 0; v < G->V; v++){
     printf("%2d:", v);
      for (w = 0; w < G->V; w++)
         if (G->adj[v][w] == 1)
            printf(" %2d", w);
      printf("\n");
  }

}

void DIGRAPHdfs( Digraph G) {
Stack *s1 = init(); //There's no error when I create a stack
push(3,s1); //I get a compilation error when I try to use the push function (The same for "pop").

Vertex v;
count = 0;
for (v = 0; v < G->V; v++)
     pre[v] = -1;
for (v = 0; v < G->V; v++)
     if(pre[v] == -1)
         dfsR(G,v);

for (v = 0; v< G->V;v++)
     printf("%d ",pre[v]);
printf("\n");
}


void dfsR(Digraph G, Vertex v) {

Vertex w;
pre[v] = count++;
for(w = 0; w < G->V; w++)
     if(G->adj[v][w] != 0 && pre[w] == -1)
          dfsR(G,w);

}

int DIGRAPHreach( Digraph G, Vertex s, Vertex t) {
Vertex w;
for (w = 0; w< G->V; w++)
     lbl[w] = 0;
reachR(G,s);
if (lbl[t] == 0) return 0;
else return 1;
}

void reachR (Digraph G, Vertex v) {

Vertex w;
lbl[v] = 1;
for (w = 0; w < G->V; w++)
  if(G->adj[v][w] == 1 && lbl[w] == 0)
    reachR(G,w);
}
```

#### graph.h

```
#define Vertex int

typedef struct digraph *Digraph;

Digraph DIGRAPHinit(int V);
int **MATRIXint(int r, int c, int val);
void DIGRAPHinsertA(Digraph G, Vertex v, Vertex w);
void DIGRAPHremoveA(Digraph G, Vertex v, Vertex w);
void DIGRAPHshow(Digraph G);
void DIGRAPHdfs( Digraph G);
void dfsR(Digraph G, Vertex v);
void reachR (Digraph G, Vertex v);
int DIGRAPHreach( Digraph G, Vertex s, Vertex t);
```

#### stack.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"
#define N 5
struct stack {
    int n; //The quantity of elements of the stack
    int vector[5]; //The stacks as a vector.
};
//Initialization of the stack
Stack* init(){
    Stack *s;
    s = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (s == NULL){
        printf("FATAL ERROR!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    s->n = 0;
    return s;
}
//Push Operation
void push(int q,Stack*s){
    //Checks stack overflow
    if (s->n == N){
        printf("Stack Overflow!\n");
        exit(1);
    }   
    s->vector[s->n] = q;
    s->n++;
}
int pop(Stack*s){
    int v;
    if (s->n == 0){
        printf("There's no element in the stack!\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    s->n--;
    v = s->vector[s->n];

    return v;

}
void print_stack(Stack*s){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<s->n; i++){
        printf("vector[%d] = %d \n",i, s->vector[i]);
    }
}
```

#### stack.h

```
typedef struct stack Stack;
Stack* init();
void push(int q,Stack*s);
void print_stack(Stack*s);
int pop(Stack*s);
```

Comment: Are you using an ancient C90 compiler? If so, that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Other problems not related to the specific question: - You should use real variable names instead of cryptic one-letter names. - You should allocate real 2D arrays, not fragmented lookup tables segmented all over the heap. - Your header files are missing header guards (could possibly be related to the problem as well). - Never hide pointers behind typedefs, not even if they are pointers to incomplete type. - Look up "const correctness" and implement it for all your function parameters. - Casting the value of malloc is pointless and possibly dangerous if you are using an ancient C90 compiler.

Comment: @Lundin C90 is not that ancient. For example, Microsoft didn't even start to support C99 until 2013 and their support is far from complete even today.

Comment: @FUZxxl Looking how anything computer-related have developed during the past 25 years, something from 1990 is incredibly ancient. As a kid in 1990, I got in touch with my very first computer, a 286 with DOS 4.0. Does it sound like something you would like to use today? And what Microsoft does and does not is a very poor argument to justify anything... If they are 14 years behind everyone else and too incompetent to make a conforming implementation of C, that's too bad for them, why should I care?

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Lundin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compiler seems to be an ANSI C compiler. In ANSI C, all variable declarations must be located at the top of a block. No statements are allowed between variable declarations. To fix your error, move the `push()` call below the declaration of `v`:

```
void DIGRAPHdfs( Digraph G) {
    Stack *s1 = init(); //There's no error when I create a stack
    Vertex v;
    push(3,s1); //I get a compilation error when I try to use the push function (The same for "pop").

    count = 0;
    for (v = 0; v < G->V; v++)
         pre[v] = -1;
    for (v = 0; v < G->V; v++)
         if(pre[v] == -1)
             dfsR(G,v);

    for (v = 0; v< G->V;v++)
         printf("%d ",pre[v]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning, C only allowd the declaration of variables in the beginning of a block. You can change your code:

```
void DIGRAPHdfs( Digraph G) {
Stack *s1 = init(); //There's no error when I create a stack
Vertex v; // Declaration moved to before any statements.
push(3,s1);
```

Or you can change your compilation to adhere to a later standard. For `gcc`, the default is to use the c90 standard. If you add the flag `-std=c99` `gcc` will use the c99 standard. If you use another compiler, check the documentation for the appropriate compiler option.